# how to pass values for the base class constructor in the inherited constructor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

I have to classes car and vehicle I am trying to use parametrized constructor to set values for the Car object members but it gives errors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class vehicle {
    int wheels ;
    double price ;
    std::string color ;
    
public:
    vehicle(int , double , std::string ) ;
    void initialize (int , double , std::string ) ;
    ~vehicle (void) ;
};

class car : public vehicle {
    int load ;
    double weight ;
    
public:
    car (int , double  , int wheels , double price , std::string color ) ;
    void initialize (int , double , std::string , int , double ) ;
    ~car (void) ;
};
car::car(int load , double weight , int wheels , double price , std::string color ):  vehicle (wheels ,price , color )
{
    this->load = load ;
    this->weight = weight ;
}
vehicle::vehicle(int w,double p,std::string c)
{
    initialize(w,p,c);
}
void vehicle::initialize(int w,double p,std::string c)
{
    wheels = w;
    price = p;
    color = c;
}
```

it gives an error in the car Constructor line

Comment: `car::car(int load , double weight , Engine engi )` -- This does not match the declaration in the class.  The declaration has 6 parameters -- this should also have 6 parameters.

Comment: _"it gives errors"_. What are the errors?

Comment: Drew Dormann.  Constructor for 'car' must explicitly initialize the base class 'vehicle' which does not have a default constructor and Expected '{' or ',

Comment: Also (ignoring your error of defining a constructor that has not declared) this `car::car(int load , double weight , Engine engi ):  vehicle (int wheels ,double price , std::string color )` is wrong.   The initialiser list for the constructor of `car` needs to pass values to the `vehicle` constructor, such as `car::car(int load , double weight , Engine engi ):  vehicle (4 , 10000, RED )`  where `4` represents the number of wheels , `10000` represents a particular price, and RED specifies a red colour.

Comment: @Peter i edited the code as you said and it gives me the same errors ```car::car(int load , double weight, int wheels , double price, std::string color ) :  vehicle ( wheels , price , color )```

Comment: @Ayoub - That's because you haven't addressed the fact that the constructor declared in the class body and your definition of it have different signatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicitly call your base constructor and with constructor initializer list you can greatly simplify your code:

```
#include <string>
class vehicle {
    int wheels ;
    double price ;
    std::string color ;
    
public:
    vehicle(int wheels, double price, std::string color) : 
        wheels(wheels), price(price), color(color){}
};

class car : public vehicle {
    int load ;
    double weight ;
    
public:
    car (int load, double weight , int wheels, double price, std::string color ) : 
        vehicle(wheels, price, color), load(load), weight(weight){}
};

int main() {
    car c(4, 1500, 4, 36000, "white");
}
```